# asp mvc how to passs multi selected value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hi friend i want to pass multi selected value  view to controller but my view pass only single selection my code is here
              public ActionResult Index()
        {

```
        var location = new[]{

                  "select","Hyderabad","Tirupati","Vijayawada","Vishakapatnam","Itanagar","Dispur",          
"Guwahati","Raipur","Goa","Ahmedabad","Bharuch",
         "Godhra","Jamnagar","Kheda","Rajkot","Surat","Vadodara","Faridabad","Gurgaon","Shimla","Dra  
 ss","Hiranagar","Poonch","Dhanbad","Ranchi","Bangalore","Hassan","Hubli","Karwar","Mangalore","Mysore","Udupi","Alappuzha","Kannur",
"Kochi","Kollam","Kottayam","Kozhikode","Palakkad","Pathanamthitta","Thiruvananthapuram","Thrissur","Bhopal","Indore","Aurangabad", 
"Mumbai","Nagpur","Nasik","Pune","Thane",
"Imphal","Shillong","Aizawl","Kohima","Bhubaneswar","Rourkela","Amritsar","Chandigarh","Jalandhar","Ludhiana","Jaipur","Jodhpur","Udaipur","Gangtok","Chennai","Coimbatore","Karur","Madurai","Thirunelveli","Trichi","Agartala","Delhi"    ,"Pondicherry","Allahabad","Lucknow","Varanasi","Kanpur","Durgapur","Kharagpur","Kolkata"

                };
        var Location = from d in location orderby d ascending select d;

        ViewData["Location"] = new MultiSelectList(Location);
```

view form code

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("candidatesearch","Process",FormMethod.Post)){ %>
<%:Html.ListBox("location", ViewData["Location"] as MultiSelectList)%><br />
<input id="location" type="submit" value ="Search"/>
```

another action method is

```
    public ActionResult candidatesearch(string location )
   {
 string rg = "";
         string[] candidatelocation = location.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i <= candidatelocation.Length;i++ )
                {
                     rg=rg+candidatelocation[i];

                }
                Response.Write(rg);
}
```

but this controller get only single value i can select multiple value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
public ActionResult candidatesearch(string location )
```

To

```
public ActionResult candidatesearch(string[] location )
```

Each item in the list should be an index in the array. Instead of your split you can then do:

```
foreach(var item in location)
{
    //do something with item
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just remember to select as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of above answer you can use

```
       public ActionResult candidatesearch(FormCollection formValues )
         {

              string[] location = formvalues["Your_ListBox_value"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

          }
```

This is more useful if you want access many form values from your view in your controller . Use Firebug to see the generated IDs for your ListBox , Checkboxes and many more . If you find this answer useful then please mark it as an answer so that others will get  benefit .